# Permission Denied - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Thanks for the support...

I uploaded a theme update to Magento 2, and run all the commands needed (Please find them below), but I'm still getting "500 Internal Server Error error". And when I checked logs in "public_html/var/log/exception.log" I see the error

```
[2021-12-14 08:46:23] main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor does not exist at /home/.../public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:26)"} []
```

Commands I already run several times...

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

chmod -R 0777 generated

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

rm -rf pub/static/*

rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/page_cache

find ./pub/media/catalog -type f -exec chmod 777 {} ;

Comment: Did you tried with composer install once

Comment: Hi @Venkat Thanks for your support. I'm not sure if you meant reinstalling composer? But yes, I did reinstall composer.

Comment: whats your magento version? var/generation is from really old magento versions. it is now called "generated" and located in the shop-root

Comment: Through this command [php bin/magento setup:di:compile] Interceptor class will generate. So please check generated folder permission. If its local environment give 777 permission on generated folder [sudo chmod -R 0777 generated]

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission issues, try the following commands :

```
cd {{YOUR_PROJECTS_DIR}}/{{PROJECT_NAME}}
sudo find var/ generated/ vendor/ pub/static/ pub/media/ app/etc/ -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
sudo find var/ generated/ vendor/ pub/static/ pub/media/ app/etc/ -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
sudo chown -R {{YOUR_USER_NAME}}:www-data . # make sure to run this from your host system!
```

This should fix any permission issues you have.

Comment: Hi Petar. Thanks for the support. 

I ran the commands you suggested, but when I got to the last one...

"sudo chown -R {{YOUR_USER_NAME}}:www-data . # make sure to run this from your host system!

I ran...

sudo chown -R /home/USERNAME/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php

But I get the error, "chown: missing operand after ‘/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php’

Comment: ex: sudo chown -R root:root . 
=>  where root is folder owner, you need to add folder owner name

Comment: @P.Paul the last command is a linux command and has nothing to do with magento. `{{YOUR_USER_NAME}}` is the name of the current linux user. Firstly open the terminal, write `who` to get the current user. After that replace `{{YOUR_USER_NAME}}` with the user you got from the `who` command

Comment: @PetarBorisovski Thanks! Yes, that's exactly what I did... I didn't want to post the cPanel username, that's why I replaced it in the comment with "USERNAME". So when I ran the command, I got the error, "chown: missing operand after ‘/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php"

Answer (score 0):

There might be some permission issues.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Try the following command once:

> find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ; && find . -type f -exec chmod 644
> {} ; && chmod u+x bin/magento